# Why does Django [Rest Framework] pass the data through OrderedDict and back, isn't it just a waste of compute?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

After reading [this blog post](https://www.dabapps.com/blog/api-performance-profiling-django-rest-framework/), I looked into using `.values()` and skip DRF serialization altogether. So now I'm curious, the natural representation is in a dictionary that looks so close to proper JSON, why bother with DRF at all?

This is the natural representation from `.values()`:

```
[
    {'type': 'Zone', 'many': False, 'id': 1, 'rank': 0},
]
```

And this is after going all the way through the Django ORM and a serializer:

```
[
    OrderedDict(
        [
            ('id', 1),
            ('type', 'Zone'),
            ('many', False),
            ('rank', 0)
        ]
    ),
]
```

And this is the final valid JSON output (changed F to f, should've just used 0 and 1):

```
[
    {'type': 'Zone', 'many': false, 'id': 1, 'rank': 0},
]
```

Obviously this is for gets, I will use the serializers to validate posts. What is the point of doing things the DRF way with the APIView, Serializer, and Response? I don't use throttling, and permissions/authentication can be easily implemented without DRF with far better readibility. So right now it seems useless to use DRF for gets, why not just use a normal django view with json.dumps or JSONEncoder?

Comment: .. then don't use DRF ^^.. it's a framework, it has lot's of stuff: throttling, authentication, renderers, filtering, pagination, versioning, schemas, etc but in the end, if you only need a list of elements you don't need the whole framework, just do a json.dumps

Comment: @pleasedontbelong That conflicts with the blog I linked: "Please: don't do this. If you do nothing else other than use Django REST framework's plain APIView and ignore the generic views, serialization, routers and other advanced functionality, you'll still be giving yourself a big advantage over using plain Django for writing your API."

Answer (score 0):

REST serializer is not just wrapping a dict into OrderedDict. It is dealing with:

- nested relations (probably the most complicated part)
- field type conversion (not all python types are easily converted to/from strings, like dates)
- you can customize what fields/relations/nested fields you want to serialize, can customize how each field should be serialized (calculated fields, etc). So you can reuse same serializer for different queries, can have different serializers for the same query
- supports saving serialized data into the database (including nested relations) + field validation

Can read more [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/). For a simple use case with pulling couple plain fields out of a single table like you showed there is not much benefit in using REST serializers (though there is no harm either). You can start with serializing your query results through json directly and manually solving one issue at a time as you run into them, then maybe the benefits of using a serializer will be more clear as you will be solving the same issues they already solved.

Also there are [faster alternatives](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#third-party-packages) like Serpy (at a cost of stripped functionality/not being as polished/more work required to setup), though seeing that you probably don't have very clear picture yet of what is it you want exactly from your serializers, I wouldn't go looking for alternatives just yet.

Comment: Nested relationships only work with GETs. POSTing nested FK's needs manual coding. Field type conversions such as dates are handled by the Django JSONEncoder. I've been using Serpy for a few months now. In that case, I'll keep doing what I'm doing, Serpy can't POST, and AFAIConcerned, that's the only purpose for a serializer I know of.

Comment: @DavidTan So your real question was what are the benefits of REST serializers over Serpy? Or you are really trying to understand why they are using OrderedDict in their implementation? Just it sounded like you had no idea what is the purpose of using any serializer at all in that question so I tried to dumb it down. Serpy is doing just the serializing part and nothing else just like you said and doing it fast (it doesn't handle related models as smoothly but you obviously already sorted it all out), so if this is the only feature you need then what is your concern?

Comment: "Or you are really trying to understand why they are using OrderedDict in their implementation?" Yes, this is it. My problem right now is I think they're going in a circle (again only for GETs) for no purpose. Please prove why I am wrong :)